# Is there any better way to encapsulate an array?

Tags: c#, arrays, encapsulation

How I do it currently:

```
class Foo
{
    public int[] A { get { return (int[])a.Clone(); } }
    private int[] a;
}
```

I think it's bad because it creates a clone and casts whenever I access it. I know I can work around it by introducing an additional variable like this

```
var foo = new Foo();
// as soon as you have to access foo.A do this
int[] fooA = foo.A;
// use fooA instead of foo.A from now on
```

but still it just looks bad.

I also dislike the java way of encapsulating

```
int get(int index) { return a[index]; }
```

because I dont get the advantages of using an array.

Is there any better way to do this?

edit: I want an array of encapsulated variables. The problem is that

```
public int[] A { get; private set; }
```

is not an array of encapsulated variables because I can modify elements of the array from outside of the class.

edit: It should also work with multidimensional arrays

Comment: What precise advantages are you looking at? You could add an indexer into `Foo`, perhaps. It's really unclear what you're trying to achieve, I'm afraid.

Comment: you can create an iterator for the array. but it's unclear what you want to achieve.

Comment: I just want an array of encapsulated variables

Comment: You need to be a lot more specific than that. Encapsulation is really a way too generic term - why and how exactly are you trying to encapsulate what? Why are you cloning the array? Perhaps an immutable array would be a better choice?

Comment: Why are you making a clone of the array? Are you trying to make it readonly? If so, you could use an indexer and only specify a `get` accessor.  You could also wrap it in a `ReadOnlyCollection<int>`.

Comment: Is it that important? Every non-primitive variable with standard getter returns reference to object in C# or Java. It is basic concept of these languages.

Comment: I'm going to echo and narrow down what Jon Skeet said: when you say that when you use `int Get(int index) { ... }` you "dont get the advantages of using an array", what advantages are you referring to? Just syntax?

Comment: @31eee384 LINQ stuff mostly. But now that I think of it, it really isn't that bad because you dont use LINQ on multidimensional arrays. I think I'm gonna use the get(index) way.

Answer (score 1):

Arrays implement `IReadOnlyList<T>` which exposes all of the relevant information you want (an iterator, an indexer, count, etc.) without exposing any of the mutable functionality of the array.

```
class Foo
{
    public IReadOnlyList<int> A { get { return a; } }
    private int[] a;
}
```

Comment: This approach doesnt work if the array is multidimensional.

Comment: @foxneSs And do you have multidimensional arrays?  Can they be refactored into a different type of data structure that could be more effectively exposed in a read only manor?  If you answered yes and no respectively, then you'll need to create your own read-only wrapper, modeled after `IReadOnlyLIst`, but with multiple dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you could use an iterator/generator to return the items as requested:

```
class Foo
{
    public IEnumerable<int> A
    {
        get
        {
            foreach (int i in a)
                yield return i;
        }
    }
    private int[] a;
}
```

... then iterate over them normally or use LINQ to get them as a new array or other type of collection:

```
int[] arr = foo.A.ToArray();
```

Comment: I should note that the `IReadOnlyList<T>` solution does not solve the problem -- by returning the array boxed as an `IReadOnlyList<int>`, you can simply cast it back to an `int[]` outside the object and you will have a reference to the original array. After which you can modify the contents to your heart's content.

Comment: code had an error `(int i in A)`, has been corrected.

Comment: Well, if you want to be that pedantic, one could use reflection to get the array field of the iterator returned by this object and mutate it.  At the end of the day you can only do so much to prevent someone from abusing their own system.  Neither solution's public API exposes mutable operations, and both can be hacked into finding the non-public versions.  This is really just the illusion of added security, without any added security.

Comment: Encapsulation is like a door lock. Anyone who really really wants to do so can still get past it, by breaking down the door or busting a window. It's still better than not bothering to lock the door at all, though. Alternatively, I could just hand you a gun with which to shoot yourself in the foot, or you can go try to find and break into the gun safe where it's stored.

Either way, boxing is not encapsulation. You can't 'accidentally' use reflection to modify a field, but you can conceivably accidentally modify an array reference you obtained via IReadOnlyList.

Comment: How are you *accidentally* going to modify the ready only list *accidentally*?  You'd need to explicitly go out of your way to use reflection to find the underlying type, then cast to that, then use a mutation operation.  Only exposing the relevant information through an interlace is an entirely acceptable means of exposing the information that you want to expose.  It provides a comparable amount of protection to your solution.  To stick with your analogy, using an interface is like a door lock and encapsulation is like a deadbolt.

Answer (score 0):

Why not expose A as a implementation of [IReadOnlyList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh192385(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
class Foo
{
    public IReadOnlyList<int> A { get { return a; } }
    private int[] a;
}
```

This allows you to return the Array as a collection where they can use the index but cannot change the contents of the array itself.

Answer (score -1):

sounds like you need an indexer

```
...
public int this[int i]{
  get{return a[i];}
  set{a[i] = value;}
}
....
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx

Comment: the requirements are unclear, i actually expect the real solution is not naked reads or writes to the array but some mediating code. I am simply showing the enabling syntax

Comment: indexer wouldnt work if I wanted to encapsulate more than one array